# Prove that $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(A_i \setminus \cup_{j=1}^{i-1}A_j) $

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I would like to show that

$$
\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(A_i\setminus \bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1}A_j\right)
$$

for $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ a family of set.

First of all, I should explain the notation since they are old (one used in France in the 1970s).

For $A$ and $B$ two disjoint sets we denote their union by $A + B$, that's why the $\sum$ appears.

For the proof, here is my attempt :

For $n=1$ the result is clear. We suppose the result holds for $n-1$, we would like to show it holds for $n$. We have

$$
\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i = \left\{ \bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}A_i\right\}\cup A_{n} = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(A_i\setminus\bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1}A_j\right)\cup A_n
$$

Put $C = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(A_i\setminus\bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1}A_j\right)$ and $D = A_n $. We need to show  that :

$$
C\cup D = C + (D\setminus C)
$$

Consider $x\in C\cup D$, it means either $x\in C$ or $x\in D$ which is equivalent to have either $x\in C$ or $x\in (D\setminus C)$, but these two last sets are clearly disjoints so we conclude that $C\cup D = C + (D\setminus C)$

Is this correct ? I have the feeling to cheat at the end of the proof even if (at least I think) the intuition is clear for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is perfect. My understanding is that you are worried about the $A\cup B=A\cup(B\setminus A)$ part. I think that it's merely the fact that this is so fundamental that you worry the argument is not sufficient. I'll do a bit more to illustrate the argumentation, namely I show that $A\cup B=(A\cap B)\cup(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)$. For $x\in A\cup B$ we have $x\in A$ or $x\in B$ (the logic *or*). First, assume that $x\in A$. Further, assume that $x\in B$, then we have $x\in A\cap B$. Otherwise, we have $x\in A$ and $x\not\in B$, so $x\in A\setminus B$. Now, let's turn to the remaining case $x\not\in A$. Then we have $x\in B$, and further $x\in B\setminus A$ since $x\not\in A$.

Conversely, for $x\in (A\cap B)\cup(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)$ we consider the three cases. For $x\in A\cap B$ we have $x\in A$ and hence $x\in A\cup B$, and the other two follow analogously. This completes the proof.

The fact fact the three sets on the RHS are disjoint is fairly immediate.

Comment: Many thanks for this answer sincerely. You got into my mind: this is exactly the problem I had that you describe in your message at the beginning and this is exactly the kind of argument I would have liked to use to finish the proof.